# INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopesApi

Tags: docusignapi

Getting the following error when trying to create an envelope using the DocuSign Ruby gem (docusign_esign (2.0.0)).

```
{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "Non-static method requires a target."
}
```

Steps:

1. I get an access token, using request_jwt_user_token
2. I create the envelope with the following code.

```
    def create_envelope(signer, filename)
        envelope_definition = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new({
        status: 'sent',
        templateId: 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-a598-f49efba2e72f',
      })

      signer = DocuSign_eSign::TemplateRole.new({
        email: signer[:email],
        name: signer[:name],
        roleName: 'signer',
      })

      cc = DocuSign_eSign::TemplateRole.new({
        email: 'xxx@xxxx.com',
        name: 'xxxx',
        roleName: 'cc',
      })

      envelope_definition.template_roles = [signer, cc]
      envelope_definition
    end
```

3. And finally send it off to DocuSign. Base path being `'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'`. As mentioned, the envelopes_resp is what gives me the `400` error.

```
    base_path = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'
    envelope = create_envelope.call(signer, filename)

    configuration = DocuSign_eSign::Configuration.new
    configuration.host = base_path
    api_client = DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.new configuration
    api_client.default_headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{auth_resp.access_token}"
    envelopes_api = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopesApi.new api_client

    envelopes_resp = envelopes_api.create_envelope(config[:account_id], envelope)
```

Comment: The error message indicates your application is making a GET call to the `/accounts/[account_id]/envelopes` endpoint, instead of a POST, which is weird

Comment: Right, that was my thought too. As it appears to be expecting the id of the envelope...however it hasn't been created yet.

Using the DocuSign API, so it's a bit of a black box, which granted for my use case, I'd like to keep that way - however it appears to be using the wrong HTTP method as you mentioned.

Comment: can you please try to use latest version of the gem? 3.4.0 (https://rubygems.org/gems/docusign_esign/) and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Ugh, slight update - I'm actually getting different Error, the error posted above was taken from Postman...where I did do a GET /facepalm. Error that I get on the server side is actually

I've updated the question with the proper error.

I will try latest gem.

Comment: Got the 3.4.0 Gem, still same issue.

Comment: I created a blank template, rather than one with key/vals expected on the PDF, seems to work now - so my guess is I'm getting the error because the template was expecting a body with key values, and I was testing with no values passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working Ruby code example [here](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-ruby/blob/main/app/services/e_sign/eg009_use_template_service.rb).
I also would recommend you use the [DocuSign Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) to generate a ZIP file with working Ruby code in case you can't get it work still.